# Sklearn RFE with pandas get_dummies

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, categories, rfe

I'm trying to understand how I can use sklearn RFE for a linear regression model when I have categorical columns I created with pandas get_dummies

I have a dataset and the layout is:

```
y = Carsales
X = Unemployment, Queries, CPI_energy, CPI_all, Month(comes in as an int)
```

The first thing I do is convert the Month to object then category (converting straight to category type wasn't working in pandas).

```
df['MonthFac'] = df['Month'].astype('object')
df['MonthFac'] = df['MonthFac'].astype('category')
```

Then I create my X, y:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
cols = ['Unemployment','Queries','CPI_energy','CPI_all']
X = pd.concat([train[cols],(pd.get_dummies(train['MonthFac']))], axis = 1)
y = train['ElantraSales'].values

lm1 = LinearRegression()

lm1.fit(X,y)
```

Then I want to use RFE:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

selector = RFE(lm1,step=1, n_features_to_select = 2)
selector.fit(X,y)
```

Simple RFE looking for 2 features, however the result is that it ranks 2 of the month columns as 1, I technically only would need to only if 1 of the month columns was rank 1 then I would that the 'MonthFac' variable is significant in building my model, I want to know what is the other top ranked variable to use.

Or am I just supposed to use my deductive reasoning to figure out what other variable to use based on the `selector.ranking_` output?

Compared to R, sklearn learning curve is a lot higher it seems.

Also am I doing Categorical values right in pandas/sklearn? In R, all I had to do was `as.factor` and BAM it did all of this.

One more question, if I wasn't sure what the optimum amount of features to I would think I could create a loop selector R^2/R^2 adj/MSE and print them out but since I have those additional month columns would my loop go to 16 cause there is essentially 16 features, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: My apologies, thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem at all. :-) Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, each dummy variable is considered as a distinct feature (take your 12 month dummy as example, it would produce 11/12 dummy variable. Taking Jan as benchmark constant, the coefficients of the other 11 dummies tell you about whether a particular month has a different mean constant than Jan), so it make perfect sense that `RFE` selects two month dummy features for you.

However, since you use a default `LinearRegression` in `RFE`, and `RFE` use `.coef_` to rank feature importances, you should set `LinearRegression(normalize=True)`. Otherwise, selecting features based on linear regression coefficients is meaningless.

Comment: how can I change RFE to use R^2 instead?

Comment: @Neil You can't. `RFE` will rank features according to either `.coef_` (regression) or `.feature_importances_` (tree-based). But when you normalize your features in `LinearRegression`, the `.coef_` gives very close approximation to the variance explained by that particular feature, that is `R2`. Actually, that's why `RFE` will make feature selection based on `.coef_`.

Comment: Ahh okay, so in general for a dataset like this is there a best practice method to determining what features to use? Like look at P-values? AIC(I don't think I can calculate that with sklearn on a linear regression model it seems) ?

Comment: @Neil You can do a `GridSearchCV` to determine how many features would give you the best cross-validation result. Alternatively, set it to some fixed number such as 10 or 20 with the aim to keep the model parsimonious is also acceptable.